# Font problem in writting pdf file

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf-generation

I have an application that can write string to pdf file. I want to write data in tabular format so i formatted the string and did write operation. Text shows up in pdf file but its not in proper format. How to do it?

Example :

I want text to be shown as:

Name    Address   Phone number
Aditya  Pune      xxxxxxxx

It is actually shown as:

Name    Address   Phone number
Aditya     Pune      xxxxxxxx

I have used stringByPaddingToLenght method. So all strings are of same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mono-space font solved my problem.